# Color Background different using Same class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have four `<div>` box each are placed one inside another and first box is define as `class="a"` and rest are define as `class="b"` now What I want to do with the help of `class="b"` I want to set third box `background-color:red` so How it can be done with only `class="b"` no different class or id I want.Will it be possible or not?

```
<div class="A">
<div class="B">
<div class="B">
<div class="B"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and if the case like this

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="B"></div>    

    </div>
```

Then how can I make third box red with help of class only
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yH8e3/) and
2nd [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yH8e3/18/)
​

Comment: Did you tried div.A .B .B .B{background:red;} ?

Comment: @Chandrakant no But now I know what to use

Comment: There are answers on the line... But the question using selector `:nth-child` is it possible with accomplish with that selector or should go else.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Yes it is possible.

Use the CSS Selector this way:

```
div.B .B .B
{
    background-color:red;
}​
```

#### Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yH8e3/3/

#### For the second case, you need to use `:nth-child` selector:

```
.A .B:nth-child(3)
{
    background-color:red;
}​
```

Comment: On a same note, it is better to avoid usage of tags in CSS. i.e., instead of `div.B` consider using just `.B`. :) Sometimes, in future, it may change from `div` to `span`. Just a use case. This is how we follow. :)

Comment: Hey if I do div.b .b .b then it color both box red why so?

Comment: No way! How? You saw the fiddle right? Which two boxes? It only affects the inner most box.

Comment: Updated the answer with `:nth-child()` too. :)

Comment: In this case when I color only second B box it also apply to 3rd one http://jsfiddle.net/yH8e3/19/

Comment: For this, you need to use this `>` immediate child selector. It works only in IE 7+, Google Chrome, Firefox and other browsers. I mean, IE 6 doesn't support. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/yH8e3/20/ And in this case, you need to give the class from the parent. :)

Answer (score 1):

try (IE7+)

```
.a > .b > .b {
  background-color:red;
}
```

or

```
.a .b .b {
  background-color:red;
}
.a .b .b .b {
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: This solution is only for coloring the second red and the third transparent or in any other color

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
div div div .B { background-color:red }
```

It Will set the innermost div's background as red.

We can use tags to apply css and also to locate the perfect div we can use it.